# SSIS: Different error propagation behaviour for different error messages?

Tags: ssis

I have a For Each Loop that is processing a bunch of Excel files. I want 'Continue with next file' behaviour on any error within that loop. For this purpose I have a Sequence Container immediately inside the For Each Loop, containing lots of control flow tasks. I have an OnError event handler on the Sequence Container which does some error logging. Propagate is set to False and MaximumErrorCount is set to 0 on the Sequence Container.

This seems to work fine in the majority of error cases. For example, if there is a truncation in a DataConversion task then the file processing aborts, logs the error message and moves on to the next file - the package is still successful. However, the behaviour is very different if there is a task validation error - for instance, if there are columns missing from the excel file - if there is a task validation error then this propagates all the way up and bombs out the package.

Edit: I am getting the following message at the For Each Loop level in the failure case which I am not getting in the other case. It looks like the validation error is propagating, but the other error isn't.

> Warning: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The
> Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1)
> reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs
> when the number of errors reaches the number specified in
> MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED error means that the number of errors encountered has reached or exceeded the MaximumErrorCount specified, which results in the failure of the package.

In your case, the error is a validation error, which occurs before the execution of the package. Even though you have set the MaximumErrorCount to 0 on the Sequence Container (which should allow unlimited errors), this doesn't prevent the For Each Loop itself from having its own MaximumErrorCount.

In other words, when an error occurs during validation, it's likely not considered as being within the scope of the specific Sequence Container since validation typically occurs prior to execution. The error isn't being captured by the error handling settings on your Sequence Container.

You may need to include some pre-execution validation steps that checks for potential issues, like for example missing columns in your Excel files, before reaching the steps that could trigger validation errors.

Also, you could also set the DelayValidation property to True for the tasks where you anticipate a validation error could occur. This means the validation for the component will occur at run-time rather than at package load time. However, this just delays the validation error and if a validation error occurs at runtime, the package would fail again.

You may need to set the MaximumErrorCount to a larger number at the package or For Each Loop level. However, I don't recommend it if the validation error signifies a serious problem with your data or ETL process. Your error handling should be designed to handle errors effectively and not to avoid them. If the data structure is not correct, ignoring or delaying the error won't be helpful in the long run. It's better to catch those errors and fix them.

Comment: Many thank Amira. That all makes sense. DelayValidation is already set on the failing data task. As you say, I don't want to just ignore all errors, so I will just have to leave it as it is and deal with it as a support task if it happens. Most errors are data issues rather than format issues, which are handled correctly, so this shouldn't happen too often. Many thanks.